# python проблема видимости файла

Tags: python-3.x, текстовые-файлы

фалы в одной папке, если верить учебнику, все должно работать без особых извращений, но что-то идет не так...

```
PS C:\Users\vvere> & C:/Users/vvere/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/temp/work8.py
C:\Users\vvere
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\temp\work8.py", line 4, in <module>
    file = open("file.txt", 'r')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
PS C:\Users\vvere>
```

При попытке задать полный путь ошибка меняется на № 22, и Внезапно меняется название файла в аргументе

```
PS C:\Users\vvere> & C:/Users/vvere/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/temp/work8.py
C:\Users\vvere
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\temp\work8.py", line 4, in <module>
    file = open("c:\temp\file.txt", 'r')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\temp\x0cile.txt'
PS C:\Users\vvere>
```

[image: Ошибки порождаются вот этим]

Comment: Ничего не внезапно, `\f` это escape-последовательность, соответствующая символу [0C «Смена страницы»](https://symbl.cc/ru/000C/). Не забывайте экранировать спецсимволы и проверять текущую рабочую папку

Comment: ``open(r"c:\temp\file.txt", 'r')`` - ``r`` перед открывающей кавычкой. https://pythobyte.com/python-raw-strings-67483/

Comment: Немного запоздалый thanks, все получилось